# Сложности в получении стилей нативным JS

Tags: javascript

Хочу получить высоту элемента. Пишу следующим образом:

```
    let header = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style;
    console.log(header);
```

В консоли получаю объект `CSSStyleDeclaration`. И в нём все значения свойств пустые. А я рассчитывал получить объект с наполненными данными.

[image: Результат]

Как я могу получить не просто то значение, которое в CSS прописано, а уже высчитанное значение в пикселях? Ведь иногда в качестве значения высоты может быть `auto` или `calc()`

Интересует решение **только** на нативном JS.

Comment: `element.getBoundingClientRect()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

• `getElementsBy...` — собирает "живой" список элементов, который обновляется при каждом обращении. Вместо этого можно использовать `querySelectorAll` - он один раз собирает список и всё. А в вашем случае, `querySelector` — находит первый элемент и останавливается.

• Объект `element.style` хранит только то, что реально написано в HTML-элементе, в атрибуте `style="..."`:

```js
let header = document.querySelector('.header').style;

console.log(header);
```

```html
<div class="header" style="align-content: center;"></div>
```

Все примененные стили можно достать через `getComputedStyle( elem )`. Но это объект с сотнями свойств. Если нужны координаты элемента и его ширина / высота, можно (нужно) вместо него использовать `elem.getBoundingClientRect()`. А если только высота: `elem.offsetHeight, elem.clientHeight` — первое дает высоту с учетом рамки, второе - без:

```js
let header = document.querySelector('.header');

console.log( "Computed → " + getComputedStyle( header ).height );
// Строка с числом + "px". Хочет дополнительно parseFloat("165px") → 165

/*******************************/

let rect = header.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log( "Rect object → " + JSON.stringify(rect) );
console.log( "Rect.height → " + rect.height );

/*******************************/

let inner = header.clientHeight;
let outer = header.offsetHeight;

console.log( "clientHeight → " + inner ); // число
console.log( "offsetHeight → " + outer ); // число
```

```css
.header {
  height: calc(100vh / 2);
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="align-content: center;"></div>
```