# Редактирование текста по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Нужно сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку, можно было редактировать текст что в параграфе. Сразу в голову пришла идея сделать через `textarea`.
Но никак не могу сделать так, чтобы этот textarea был по длине и высоте такой же, как и текст в параграфе. Textarea создается в стандартном размере, и из за этого текст размещается в этой области. Как сделать так, чтобы размеры textarea становились такие же, как и текст в параграфе?
Подскажите, может есть какие-то более хорошие решения, или как исправить это.
Вот пример:

```js
function changeText () {
  let text = document.getElementById('text');
  text.innerHTML = `<textarea>${text.textContent}</textarea>`
}
```

```html
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, totam.</p>
<button onclick = "changeText()" >Change</button>
```

Comment: Первое что приходит в голову - это перед созданием текстарии высчитать размеры параграфа и потом уже эти размеры задать текстарии. П.С. и я бы не заменял текст параграфа, а добавил бы текстарию сразу, но скрытую и по нажатию на кнопку вычислял размеры параграфа, задал размеры текстарии, скрыл параграф, отобразил текстарию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует атрибут `contentEditable` ) Его можно добавить на любой HTML-элемент, и он станет редактируемым.

Можно еще добавить атрибут `spellcheck="false"`, если не хочется видеть красное подчеркивание текста в режиме редактирования.

```js
let edit = document.querySelectorAll('.edit');
let text = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

for( let i = 0; i < edit.length; i++ ){
  let editMode = false;
  
  edit[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    if( editMode ) {
      this.textContent = "Edit";
      text[i].removeAttribute('contentEditable');
    } else {
      this.textContent = "Ok";      
      text[i].setAttribute('contentEditable', true);
      text[i].focus();
    }
    
    editMode = !editMode;
  });
}
```

```css
p {
  padding: 5px;
}

p[contentEditable] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, totam.</p>
<button class="edit">Edit</button>

<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, totam.</p>
<button class="edit">Edit</button>
```

`!` — это логическое "НЕ". `editMode = !editMode` — Оно превращает `false → true` и наоборот. После каждого клика, значение переменной переключается.

---

Касаемо textarea, здесь описано, [как получить стили / размеры элемента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1046997/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-js/1047001#1047001). Если очень хочется измерить параграф и подогнать туда textarea с тем же размером)

Comment: ну уж не на любой элемент и не по всех браузерах. IE/Edge емнип ячейки таблицы до сих пор не умеют редактировать.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй добавить атрибут "cols" для того ,что бы задать ширину